# Set up Solidity with VS Code - Beginner

Tags: solidity, visual-studio-code

I just started learning about Solidity and i want to learn more about smart contracts and all the universe about Solidity programming.

So i downloaded VS Code and i installed the Solidity extension in my VS code.

**After then what steps do i have to do to begin writing solidity?
Do i have to download nodejs or truffle?**

I ve search on the internet there are not tutorials about setting up Solidity on VS Code. I need to help me about setting up all the details so the Solidity works as it should.

Sorry if it is a stupit question, but i really need help
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way to start coding Solidity is using [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/), which is a web-based IDE that allows you to code and compile smart contracts without the need of installing anything else.

VSCode is a great editor to write code and if you use a Solidity extension, this will give you hints when coding and options to compile (read the extension documentation to know how to compile, etc)

Finally, if you want to run tests or automate deployments, then you can go for frameworks such as Truffle or Hardhat, that will require Node.js to be installed.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the advice. I really like VS Code design and i also use it for python so thats why i want to use Solidity in VS Code as well. So i downloaded the nodejs from here nodejs.org/en and i installed it. Do i have to do some other steps or other downloads to Solidity code (such as Truffle) ?

Comment: It needs VS Code Solidity extension, nodejs and then download Truffle? And them i ready to code in VScode?

Comment: To install Truffle globally, you can use 'npm install -g truffle'. Then, to start a project, in the root folder: 'truffle init' (all these commands through the terminal)

Comment: Why this Solidity extension for vscode is so buggy. Autocomplete and formatting almost never works.

Answer (score 0):

I use nodejs to compile my contracts with the solc package but I think there are other [options](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/installing-solidity.html) out there.

As for settings in VSCode, you might need to provide which version of solidity you will like to use. You can find a list of versions [here](https://etherscan.io/solcversions).

However, I highly recommend using [remix ide](https://remix.ethereum.org/) to begin writing solidity.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the advice. I really like VS Code design and i also use it for python so thats why i want to use Solidity in VS Code as well. So i downloaded the nodejs from here https://nodejs.org/en/ and i installed it. Do i have to do some other steps or other downloads to Solidity code (such as Truffle) ?

Comment: It needs VS Code Solidity extension, nodejs and then download Truffle? And them i ready to code in VScode?

Answer (score 0):

I would set up the local development in Visual Studio Code with both Remix extension and Truffle.

I have actually written an article for it [here](https://blog.cabala.co/how-i-set-up-my-local-solidity-development-environment-with-vscode-remix-and-truffle-suite-addd20ef9c)

A tl;dr is to install the Remix extension in the extension tab, which acts just like the browser version, and also install Truffle through npm, as well as Ganache for local blockchain testing.